# Providing notes for missed work

Tags: management, sickness, leave-of-absence

I hurt my hand and needed to take time off work to get it checked out by doctors. My boss is super vigilant to make sure I get a doctors note each time (he didn't even accept a nurses note and he's skeptical that different doctors are writing the notes).

I'm going to start physio therapy, and I'm not sure if physio therapists even write notes. It seems to me if I bring in the receipt it would at least prove that I was at a physio therapist.

Any advice on evidence of what to bring to my boss or how to get it?

I don't get any sick days but I don't mind not getting paid for the time I miss, or making it up at another time.

Comment: That seems weird to me - I'd be tempted to ask him (or HR) straight up "is there a belief that I'm faking this injury?" Especially since you're taking this time off unpaid - I'm having trouble wrapping my head around why they'd want a note for every doctor's appointment.

Answer (score 17):

> Any advice on evidence of what to bring to my boss or how to get it?

This is an easy one - just ask your boss what kind of evidence he wants and will accept. Then ask your health professional ahead of time to be prepared to provide that evidence.

There are no "standards" here. What is acceptable for one boss or company will not be acceptable for another. So you must find out what works in your particular situation.

And as @HorusKol correctly points out, you may need to consider local employment laws.

Comment: There may also be variation in local employment laws - for example, visiting a doctor or physio for an appointment may not necessarily be enough to trigger "sick leave", and you might have to work extra hours to make up the time (unlike being sick and seeing a doctor to write so many days off with a note).